# How to correctly extend OSM geometries?

Tags: editor, openstreetmap

for some custom use case we need to redefine some parts of OSM with data that doesn't make sense to contribute back to OSM. Basically we need to have a custom definition of sidewalk plus some other things.

Forking OSM and change the data directly wouldn't be much trouble but obviously we would lose important updates.

My question is: are there resources, tutorial or tools to do this properly? How are merges handled? Is there a way to define "deltas" to the original OSM that avoid conflicts? Is it a common scenario? Is this somehow supported by editors or other GUI tools?

Comment: This question is offtopic for StackOverflow which focuses on programming. Try asking at https://help.openstreetmap.org or https://gis.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: maybe you're right